# Fastest way to select a record from another table if doesn't exist in the first table

Tags: sql

Perhaps this is something very easy for SQL experts.

I have two tables:

```
Table A     TID    Desc
Table B     TID    Desc
```

I understand I can do `IsExists` but not sure if that is the fastest way.  The requirement is that if the record exists in Table A for a given TID, the record should be read form Table A, else from table B.  Record will definitely exist in Table B

Comment: do a left join from table b to table a and then coalesce the columns

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `Exists` will satisfy your requirement. Try using `Left Outer Join`

```
select Coalesce(A.somecol,B.somecol) 
from  tableB B 
left outer join tableA A
on B.TID = A.TID
Where B.TID = X  --Make sure you add the filter to TableB
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select isnull(A.val, B.val)   
  from B
  left join A
    on B.TID = A.TID
```

Comment: I will add Where B.TID = X and try it out.